# Can I use currying in React to make a subsequent API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, currying

I'm trying to make Pokemon cards in React, using the PokeAPI.  I would like the cards to have 2 sides, a front, and a back with expanded details.  Due to the way the API endpoints works, each individual Pokemon has to make a call to its specific endpoint to get the expanded details.  Right now I'm setting the state with the initial api call(inside of componentDidMount), that returns a non-detailed list of pokemon, including their name, and API endpoint url.  This state is stored in a class based container called "Cardcontainer", that has 2 functional components, "frontCard", and "backCard", which are rendered using props.  The backCard data is retrieved via HTTP request on a click event, on the Cardcontainer component, and the card will be flipped, revealing the details.  Everything is working, but I'm having trouble getting the details to go to the right card.  Could I use currying to solve my problem?  I'd like to keep my current design no matter what, but could I use currying to get all the details in the componentDidMount method?  How would you go about solving this?

Card Container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Frontcard from '../Components/frontCard';
import Backcard from '../Components/backCard';

class Cardcontainer extends Component {
state= {
    pokemon: [],
    cardBack: []
}

componentDidMount() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

        xhr.onload = () => {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                const pokeList = data.results;
                this.setState(
                    {   ...this.state,
                        pokemon: pokeList,

                    }
                )
            } 
            else {
                console.log('not ok')
            }
        }

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();           
}

handleClick = (e) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${e.currentTarget.firstChild.innerText}`;

    xhr.onload = () => {
        const backData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        const joined = this.state.cardBack.concat(backData)
        this.setState(
            {
                ...this.state,
                cardBack: joined
            }

        );
    }


    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

render() {

    return (
        this.state.pokemon.map((poke, index)=>{
            return (
                <div onClick={this.handleClick} 
                    className={"card-container"} 
                    key={index}
                    >
                    <Frontcard name= 
 {this.state.pokemon[index].name}/>
                    <Backcard frontName= 
 {this.state.pokemon[index].name} number={index} name= 
 {this.state.cardBack[index]} />
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}


}

export default Cardcontainer;
```

backCard:

```
import React from 'react';

const Backcard = (props) => {
const details = props;
console.log(!details.name? 'hi':details.name.name)
console.log()

return (
    <div className={"card-back"}>  
        <h4>{details.name!==props.frontName? 'hi': 
details.name.name}</h4>
    </div>
)
}

export default Backcard;
```

Comment: There's quite a few things going on here that I'd do differently. I don't think currying will help you, but what might is moving the api call into a card specific component rather than doing it in the container. Also look into the new `fetch` api instead of using xhr directly. If I have time I can do a quick mockup of how I'd structure this

Comment: @david I don't have any problem with storing the data in a different container, is it ok to have each card make an api call?  Isn't that bad practice since the only elements that actually need to show the data, are the ones that are flipped?  Thats why I'm trying to make the request onClick, but I'm learning, and don't really know.

Comment: Here's somethign for you to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/t2udky8f/
Clicking on the name will add their types to the "card"

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly your problem, there is an endpoint for each pokemon specific data (the data you show in the backcard component).

If you don´t really want to make any change in your React components, you should feed the this.state.cardback array by calling n-times in the component didmount to every specific endpoint for each pokemon (bad idea) after first retrieving the list of pokemons from where you get the subsequent url for each pokemon.

My suggestion would be to hold the data in the Cardback component itself, so it has its own state, you pass as a prop the url and then inside the Cardback component on the componentDidMount method you fetch the corresponding data.

Comment: Can you use lifecycle methods inside of functional components?  Could I just pass the url to the backCard, and use that to make the call, and fill in the state via a function passed as a prop from the container component?

Comment: Yes, you can, using React Hooks you no longer need to use classes. However, if you don´t want to change your current approach, just make your backCard a stateful component instead of a functional one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by using Currying. Currying is the concept of a function returning another function which can be executed at a different point of time and it has the snapshot of the variables of parent function.

Coming to your problem, its a good idea to fetch the data required for the component in the same component. You should pass the Pokemon id or the url on to the backCard component and perform the REST call there to fetch the data by using hooks and populate the component.

I just checked the https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon api, can you pass the URL as prop to the backCard component.

CardContainer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Frontcard from '../Components/frontCard';
import Backcard from '../Components/backCard';

class Cardcontainer extends Component {
state= {
    pokemon: [],
    cardBack: []
}

componentDidMount() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

        xhr.onload = () => {
            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                const pokeList = data.results;
                this.setState(
                    {   ...this.state,
                        pokemon: pokeList,

                    }
                )
            } 
            else {
                console.log('not ok')
            }
        }

        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();           
}



render() {

    return (
        this.state.pokemon.map((poke, index)=>{
            return (
                <div            className={"card-container"} 
                    key={index}
                    >
                    <Frontcard name= 
 {this.state.pokemon[index].name}/>
                    <Backcard frontName= 
 {poke.name} number={index} name= 
 {poke.name} url={poke.url} />
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}


}

export default Cardcontainer;
```

backCard

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';

    const Backcard = (props) => {

const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {
        const backData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        const joined = this.state.cardBack.concat(backData)
        setData(joined);
    }
    xhr.open('GET', this.props.url, true);
    xhr.send();

  }, []);

    const details = props;
    console.log(!details.name? 'hi':details.name.name)
    console.log()

    return (
        <div className={"card-back"}>  
            <h4>{details.name!==props.frontName? 'hi': 
    details.name.name}</h4>
        </div>
    )
    }

    export default Backcard;
```

Comment: Yes, I can pass the URL down via props I just realized.  Can I do it that way, without  hooks?  I just learned React without them, and just want to finish this project, and get a grip on what I learned, before learning the new methods.  I was planning on learning hooks when I'm done with this, and rewriting it using them, and Redux tho so thanks, your answer will be really helpful on my next go at this to give me an idea what to do.

Comment: Without hooks if you want to perform the REST call in CardContainer itself, then you have to pass the url to the handleClick as argument and perform the call which will ensure you have the right data.

Comment: I'm already doing that, and getting the right information tho, and if you click on them in order, it works fine. The problem is that my initial array is empty, so say if you click on Charizard(#9) first, his data goes to Bulbasaurs(#1) card back, and not to Charizards div, because then Charizard is first in the cardback array, and maps the props to Bulbasaur who is #1, because thats the logical place for Bulbasaur to get his data from.  Can I just fill an array with empty objects to start, and splice them into the right places, or would the fill method in the state overwrite everything?